# Cloudfront no_Caching parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have to AutoScalingGroups associated with an ALB.
I am trying to create a Caching and no_caching CLoudfront Distributions to my ALB,which I am testing with index.html files situated under /var/www/html/cache/index.html and var/www/html/no_cache/index.html.

I used the following behavior , after reading the AWS Documentation, but still, when I change the content of var/www/html/no_cache/index.html, I still get the old version, which means cloudfront is sending me a cached content back.

Here the photos:
[image: Config1]

[image: Config2]

is there something false in my config ? should I change something to get the result ?
Thank you so much  in advance !

Comment: Try invalidating the cache

Comment: What do you mean exactly by invalidating the cache ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the response. But I don't want to invalidate a single file. I am just testing the non-caching feature and wanted it to be applied to all the Paths with the */no_cache/* pattern. don't you have an idea about that ?

Comment: I know what you mean. The reason why I asked you to try it is that CloudFront sometimes   "remembers" the old setting. In your case, you already set to no cache but it still serves the old file. Try modifying the file again after the invalidation.

Comment: Do you think it could have sthg to do with the other behaviors ? because this behavior has precedence 2. Other Caching behaviors have precedence 1 and 0 ... could it be a reason ?

Comment: It could be. What URL are you visiting?

Comment: so for the caching version my path pattern ist:
*/cache/index.html 
for the non-caching pattern the path pattern is:
*/no_cache/index.html

http://d38efz80uxeun4.cloudfront.net/cache/index.html
http://d38efz80uxeun4.cloudfront.net/no_cache/index.html